Why is it taking 0.002sol for transaction?
Guys suppose I had 2 wallets(a and b). B wallet is empty and A wallet has 2 wif tokens and 0.006sol, if I want to send 1 wif to b wallet, then it shows to pay 0.002sol + t.fee... In solscan it shows created account with deposit of 0.002sol. So when I send wif will I get that 0.002 sol back? And what is I burn wif in B(don't worry about fee) and want to send 1 wif again, then will I again have to deposit 0.002sol? and when sent then get it back?
Thanks

no you don't get them back when you send the token. The only way to get the rent back is by closing the token account. But the 0.002 SOL will be sent to B, not given back to A. (it could go back to A, but you have to build a custom instruction for that). Going back to B is the default behavior.
If you close the token account in B, if you want to send WIF again to that same address, you will need to fund again the 0.002 SOL.

what is closing token account? Suppose when I sent 1 wif, then burn the token and want to send again to that same wallet, then will I have to pay only transaction fee

yes if you just burn the tokens and send anoher one, you will pay only for tx fees since the token account haven't been closed. Closed means that you redeem the SOL inside this account for the rent, and all data in this account is removed as well.

thanks bro for your help, but can you see if my account isn't closed??? Because as of now I can't afford to loose sol for this mistake- A wallet- 77otVFwmJcnZC78yM3hVjeU8DMz8J4wWRBDM1PYKWjbQ         transaction id- https://solscan.io/tx/43PMXS3wBzxn6CRbkfZUPbjWdU2XoanxkqLUurg4R5L44K39r57NN5H1hQRYcdkCSGAzrHjRCtdyb8aWtqJ8zXUs   because in solscan, the create account wallet address has 0sol in it
